# document is not defined react native

Tags: react-native

Hi everyone im having a problem with my react native project, and Im getting this error:
[document is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZpJg.png)

With my code im trying to use the firebase authentication with a phone number using "signInWithPoneNumber()" and when I add the "recaptchaVerifier()" I get that error.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVEYY.png)

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to post the code where you make this call.

Comment: If recaptchaVerifier needs DOM, then it won't work with react native

Comment: @RamziC. I add the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firebase code is intended to be used in a browser, where the `document` is available. The react-native option is the [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) project, but they still don't support this feature.

You can track their progress on [this issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/119).